# Android Sensorfusion library error

Tags: android, sensors

I'm using this android library to get device rotation angel

[sensorfusion] : https://github.com/goatstone/AndroidSensorFusion/blob/master/java/com/goatstone/util/SensorFusion.java

make a private sensorfusion variable by this:

```
private SensorFusion sensorFusion;
```

and add this lines to onCreate:

```
sensorFusion = new SensorFusion();
sensorFusion.setMode(SensorFusion.Mode.ACC_MAG);
```

at last when in my button listener function when i want read the angel by this i got : azimuth:0.0

```
double azimuthValue = sensorFusion.getAzimuth();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "azimuth:"+azimuthValue ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

anyone can help ?

Comment: Can you specify what your goal is?

Comment: I want to get azimuth by degree @Type-Style